# support in igraph for sparse networks

Tags: r, igraph

I am working with a sparse network dataset. The vertex id in the dataset may hold a value, between 1 and 4000. For example, a small selection of the data may include the values 2, 300, 400, 700, 3000, etc.

It's not clear to me if the igraph library only accepts a sparse dataset or expects a range of values.

Do I have to redefine/remap my dataset into a continuous data range, before I call  any igraph function, e.g  remapping the data values as follows:

- 2 becomes 1
- 300 becomes 2
- 400 becomes 3
- 700 becomes 4
- 3000 becomes 5

Then call an igraph function and do a reverse map after the Igraph function has finished or can I just call the igraph function on the range `2,300,400,700,3000` without doing any remapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`igraph` vertex and edge indices are always continuous ranges of integers, i.e. if you have 20 nodes in `R igraph` vertex indices will go from `1` to `20` and in `Python igraph` from `0` to `19`. In addition the indices are not guaranteed to remain unchanged if you add or remove elements. Consequently the solution is to create a vertex attribute with your indices. For example:

```
require(igraph)

vertices <- sample(1:4000, 20, replace=F)
source   <- sample(vertices, 40, replace = T)
target   <- sample(vertices, 40, replace = T)
edges    <- data.frame(source = source, target = target)
g        <- graph.data.frame(edges)

g
IGRAPH DN-- 20 40 --
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 2943->3671 822 ->1587 922 ->1694 822 ->1096 1694->1739 922 ->1096
[7] 922 ->1739 1739->1587 2943->2666 2891->2956 1096->822  267 ->839 
[13] 2891->2666 767 ->839  767 ->2956 1694->523  839 ->1739 1096->3641
[19] 1348->1739 350 ->839  1096->267  523 ->922  3641->1739 267 ->699 
[25] 523 ->1739 1587->699  267 ->1096 1587->3641 523 ->1587 1739->839 
[31] 1587->3641 1348->267  1694->350  1587->755  1348->922  839 ->2666
[37] 1739->699  922 ->1348 3641->2891 1096->2943
```

Notice that `igrap` automatically created the vertex attribute `name` to store the original indices, while the internal indices are `1:20` as usual. The vertex `2943` will always have this name unless you change it, while its current index is `1` but it can change upon reindexing.

```
vertex.attributes(g)
$name
[1] "2943" "822"  "922"  "1694" "1739" "2891" "1096" "267"  "767"  "839" 
[11] "1348" "350"  "523"  "3641" "1587" "3671" "2666" "2956" "699"  "755"

V(g)[1]
+ 1/20 vertex, named:
[1] 2943

V(g)[V(g)$name == 2943]
+ 1/20 vertex, named:
[1] 2943
```